# How to set indexed form variable?

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML code:

```
<input name=myvar type="hidden"/>
```

I use this simple snippet to set the value before submitting a form:

```
document.forms['form'].myvar.value='1';document.form.submit();
```

This works fine, without problems.

Because of changes in the corresponding PHP-code, I have to change the name of the variable to use an indexed variable:

```
<input name="myvar[js]" type="hidden"/>
```

I have tried these, all without success:

```
document.forms['form'].myvar[js].value='1';  // Error: "myvar" not defined
document.forms['form'].myvar['js'].value='1';  // Error: "js" not defined
document.forms['form'].myvar["js"].value='1'; // SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script
```

How can I set that variable in Javascript?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend accessing your inputs like this. Instead `document.querySelector('#form[name="myvar[js]"]).value`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access it with:

```
document.forms['form']['myvar[js]']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add id

```
<input name=myvar[js] id="myvarJS" type="hidden"/>
```

And then

```
document.getElementById("myvarJS").value='1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getElementsByName` to get the element:

```
document.getElementsByName('myvar[js]')
```